# List Conversion in C# with null values

Tags: c#, list, type-conversion

I have a list that contains numeric values stored in a `List<string>`.

The data may contain some null values.

How can I convert `List<string>` to `List<double?>`?
This is my code:

```
List<double > d2 = d1.ConvertAll(item => double.Parse(item));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  Do you know how to convert one single item?  If so, the general algorithm is create a new list, convert each item, and then add that conversion to the new list.

Comment: this is what I have tried so far:List<double > d2 = d1.ConvertAll(item => double.Parse(item));

Comment: And what problems do you have with that solution?  How are you currently handling items that can't currently be converted?

Comment: I get this error whit my code:Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @SonerGönül I'm glad someone else was faster than me or I would be getting downvoted.

Comment: why so much negative votes, sorry my question wasn't well posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = yourlist.Select(x=> string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Beware, this will throw if there are any non-null input that don't parse.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify how you want to handle input that is not `null`, but can't be parsed. I offer you three solutions.

The first solution returns `null` for all `null` input and `string`s that can't be parsed to `double`.

```
var values =
    list.Select(
        s => {
            double value; 
            if(!Double.TryParse(s, out value)) {
                return (double?)null;
            }
            return value;
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Note that this will return `null` for `null` input *and* for `string`s that don't parse to `double`s.

The second solution will bomb if you have any `string`s that are not-null and can't be parsed:

```
var values = list.Select(s => s != null ? double.Parse(s) : (double?)null)
                 .ToList();
```

Again, note that this will *throw* an exception if you encounter any non-`null` `string`s that don't parse to `double`.

A third possibility is to elide non-null `string` that can't be parsed to `double`.

```
 var values =
     list.Select(
         s => {
             double value;
             if(s == null) {
                  return new { Parseable = true, Value = (double?)null) };
             }
             else if(!Double.TryParse(s, out value)) {
                  return new { Parseable = false, Value = (double?)null) };
             }
             else {
                  return new { Parseable = true, Value = value };
             }
      )
      .Where(x => x.Parseable)
      .Select(x => x.Value)
      .ToList();
```

I actually **strongly** advise against this. Silently ignoring errors is a huge source of bugs.

Comment: Also not what he's looking for.

Comment: He asked: if the **string** was null to return null, else to parse the string.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: He did *not* specify what he wants done with non-null `string` that do not parse.

Comment: He did, but you're not checking for null.

Comment: I don't need to check for `null`. `Double.TryParse` will return `false` for `null` input, which will branch into the `if` body and return `(double?)null`, exactly as he wants.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: It's in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx): "The conversion fails if the `s` parameter is `null`, is not a number in a valid format, or represents a number less than `MinValue` or greater than `MaxValue`. This parameter is passed uninitialized."

Answer (score 0):

```
List<double?> result = myList.Select(n => n == null ? (double?)null : double.Parse(n)).ToList();
```

Comment: Try compiling the solution and see for yourself.